# Examples where roots are necessary for the solution

Tags: calculus, student-motivation, examples, concept-motivation

I currently write an article where I want to introduce roots. Thus I need to motivate them. Here I said, they can be used to find solutions of equations like $x^n=a$. Now I want to make some examples, where this problem arises. So far I found:

- What is the side length of a square with the area of $10 m^2$?
- What are the roots of the polynomial $x^2+x-1$?

What examples would you take? I do not have the feeling that mine are really convincing to study roots...

Comment: What is the hypotenuse of the isosceles right triangle with leg length one inch? (Lots of history with this.)

Comment: Are you including e.g. all 0s of polynomials? If so, what about Calculus problems where one wants the derivative (or second derivative, etc) of a polynomial (which is also a polynomial...) to be 0? I do not think there is a shortage of such problems. Maybe you could make your question a bit more specific?

Comment: How about solving for the percentage annual return which will double an investment in ten years?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Ray-tracing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(graphics)), which underlies much of high-end computer graphics (from [*Toy Story*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Story) to [*Frozen*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frozen_(2013_film)))
relies on computing the intersection of a ray line-of-sight with
a geometric object. 
For example, where does the ray $a + t v$ with parameter $t$, $a=(2,0)$, $v=(-1,\frac{1}{2})$,
intersect the unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$?
Substitution of $a + t v = \left( 2-t,\frac{t}{2} \right)$ for $(x,y)$ 
in the circle equation leads to
\begin{eqnarray}
(2-t)^2 + \frac{t^2}{4} &=& 1 \;, \\
\frac{5 t^2}{4}-4 t+3 &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
whose roots are $t=2$, or $t=\frac{6}{5}$, yielding the intersection points
\begin{eqnarray}
(x,y) &=& (0,1) \;, \\
(x,y) &=& \left( \frac{4}{5},\frac{3}{5} \right) &=& (0.8, 0.6) \;.
\end{eqnarray}

---

[image: RayCirc]

---

Because the latter point is closer to the ray origin $a$, that 
$(0.8, 0.6)$ point is the one
whose surface characteristics determine 
the color/shade of the image pixel represented by the ray line-of-sight.

Answer (score 2):

To compute the [golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio), we need to find the positive root of a quadratic equation.

Two quantities $a$ and $b$ with $a>b>0$ are said to be in the *golden ratio* if $a$ is to $b$ as $a+b$ is to $a$.

[image] (Image source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#/media/File:Golden_ratio_line.svg))

Algebraically, $$\frac a b= \frac {a+b} a.$$ If $\varphi=\tfrac a b$ denotes the golden ratio, then $$\varphi = 1+\varphi^{-1}.$$ Multiplying with $\varphi$ and rearranging gives the equation $$\varphi^2-\varphi-1=0,$$ which has a positive root $$\varphi=\frac {1+\sqrt 5} 2 \approx 1.618$$

Comment: Let $x = -\varphi$. Then $\varphi^2 - \varphi - 1 = x^2 + x - 1$, which amounts to the second bullet-point from the OP.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman ... or let $x=b/a=\varphi^{-1}$. Then you also end up with the equation $x^2+x-1=0$.